# Why does proper $G$-CW complex imply $G$ should act properly discontinuously?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

From this paper [enter link description here](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu//Leary-Nucinkis/ijlbeanCW.pdf)

$G$ denotes a discrete group. A $G$-CW-complex is a CW-complex upon which $G$ acts by permuting the cells. A $G$-CW-complex is said to be proper if each cell stabiliser is finite, which is equivalent to the requirement that $G$ should act properly discontinuously.

I wonder why proper $G$-CW complex implies $G$ should act properly discontinuously?

Comment: Every compact subset is contained in a finite union of cells.

Comment: http://www.mathreference.com/at-cw,compact.html

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you, but I need to show every point has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\cap g(U)$ is nonempty for only finitely many $g\in G$. And a CW-complex is not necessarily locally compact, I don't know how to apply your words.

Comment: the two definitions of proper discontinuity are equivalent regardless of local compactness. Take a look at Bourbaki's General Topology.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you, I am not sure about your definition of "properly discontinuous", can you state it?

Comment: The natural map $ (G,X)\to (X,X)$ is proper. I highly recommend reading Bourbaki's or Koszul's book on transformation groups

Comment: @MoisheCohen here you can see they are not generally equivalent http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions

Comment: Oh, I see: You are using wrong definition of proper discontinuity (I did not notice that you have one open set, not two). I suggest, you avoid this definition as it is inadequate. The right definition in terms of neighborhoods is that given any two points $x, y\in X$ there are neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ of these points such that $\{g\in G: gU_x\cap U_y\ne \emptyset\}$ is finite. This is the stronger definition and is equivalent to the one given in Bourbaki.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you very much! Actually, I just use the definition from Hatcher's book. And there are many Bourbakis, which one are you referring?

Comment: N. Bourbaki, "Elements of Mathematics. General Topology'', Part III.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you!

Comment: @Katherine: Have you figured out a proof? I also only see a way that Moishe Cohen's idea works if we additionally assume that $X$ is locally compact.