# Properly discontinuous action and Hausdorff/second-countable spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $E$ a topological space. We say that $G$ acts properly discontinuous in $E$ if $\forall x\in E$ exists $ U \subset E$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $gU \cap U = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow g \neq id$.

Suppose that $G$ acts properly discontinuous in $E$ and let $B=E/G$.

I know there is $\rho : E \rightarrow B$ covering map.

How can I show that $E$ is Hausdorff and second-countable space if and only if $B$ is Hausdorff and second-countable?

Comment: $B$ need not be Hausdorff, even when $E$ is Hausdorff and second-countable. See [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083696/1421); the counterexample I describe there does not have a Hausdorff quotient.

Comment: @JackLee I assumed the group finite

Comment: Ah, missed that. Sorry. Well, maybe my answer to the other question will help you get started.