# Fundamental Group of a Quotient under Group Action

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a simply connected topological space (therefore with trivial fundamental group) and $G$ a group which acts on $X$ freely. Recently I read that for fundamental group of $X/G$ holds the equation $\pi_1(X/G) =G$.

My questions are :

1. how to see it (any sources where it explained detailed; I suppose that it was deduced by a category equivalence $(Cov/X) \leftrightarrow ?$ but I forgot what was the second category).
2. Do there exist weaker conditions (explicitely if $G-$action not freely or if $X$ not simply connected) for which the equation $\pi_1(X/G) =G$ stil holds?

Comment: I know that 1. is explained in Joe Wolf's book "Spaces of Constant Curvature".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to assume more about the action than just freeness; otherwise this statement is not true. For example, $\mathbb R$ acts freely on itself by translation, and $\mathbb R$ is simply connected, but $\mathbb R/\mathbb R$ is a single point, and its fundamental group is not isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

In order to get the conclusion you want, you also have to assume that the action satisfies the following condition:

> Every $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that for all $g\in G$, $gU \cap U = \emptyset$ unless $g$ is the identity.

(Note that this implies, in particular, that $G$ acts freely.) Some authors call an action satisfying this condition a "properly discontinuous action"; but I don't like that term because different authors use it with inequivalent definitions, and also because it leads to oxymoronic expressions like "a continuous properly discontinuous action." Allen Hatcher in his book [Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) introduced the term ***covering space action*** for a continuous group action satisfying the condition above, and I've adopted that term in my books.

The basic fact is that if the action of $G$ on $X$ is a covering space action, then the quotient map $X\to X/G$ is a covering map. If in addition $X$ is simply connected, then $\pi_1(X/G)$ is isomorphic to $G$.

For more details, see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083696/1421); and for even more, see Chapters 11 and 12 in my book [*Introduction to Topological Manifolds*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441979391).

Answer (score 0):

> how to see it (any sources where it explained detailed; I suppose that it was deduced by a category equivalence $(Cov/X) \leftrightarrow ?$ but I forgot what was the second category).

If $X$ is sufficiently nice, there is a Galois connection (which is a contravariant equivalence of categories) between covers of $X$, and subgroups of $\pi_1(X).$ If $X$ is simply connected with a proper discontinuous group action $G$, then we could instead describe the equivalence between subgroups of $G$ and covers of $X/G.$

> Do there exist weaker conditions (explicitely if $G-$action not freely or if $X$ not simply connected) for which the equation $\pi_1(X/G) =G$ stil holds?

I don't know about weaker conditions. Usually we require stronger conditions: the group action must act properly discontinuously: the map $G\times X\to X\times X$ is proper, or every point has a neighborhood disjoint from the orbit of that point.