# Computing the fundamental group of $S^3 / G$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider $S^3$ defined in $\mathbb{C}$ as $$S^3 = \{(z_0, z_1) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \big\vert |z_0|^2+|z_1|^2=1 \}.$$

Now define for any natural number $n$:
$$f_n : S^3 \rightarrow S^3 : (z_0, z_1) \mapsto (e^{n \pi i/7} z_0, e^{3n \pi i/7} z_1).$$

Now it's easy to see that each $f_n$ are homeomorphisms and that $G = \{f_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a group.

I now want to compute the fundamental group of $S^3/G$. I don't really know where to start. I have some intuition that I might need the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, but I can't seem to find a way in.

Comment: Are you sure its $e^{n\pi i}z_0$ and not $e^{n\pi i/7}z_0$?

Comment: I'd have to check the question statement again. Why do you think that?

Comment: Because then it would be the action whose quotient is a lens space. As currently stated, $f_n$ fixes the circle $z_1 = 0$ pointwise for $n$ even, so the conditions in hunter's answer won't be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S^3$ is simply connected, the fundamental group identifies with $G$. See here for a full proof (+ list of hypotheses to check, all of which hold).

[Fundamental Group of a Quotient under Group Action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510619/fundamental-group-of-a-quotient-under-group-action)

Comment: I don't have a copy of this book but the point is that $S^3$ is the universal cover of this space and $G$ is the group of deck transformations of the cover, both of which you can check. (I'm reasonably sure that the correspondence between deck transofmrations and the fundamental group are covered.)

Comment: Could you give any hints on how to prove the hypothesis of the action of $G$ being properly discontinuous?

Comment: @Geigercounter a finite group acting freely on a Hausdorff space always acts properly discontinuously. (Separate the points $gx$ from each other by open sets using the Hausdorff property -- you need the group to be finite here or else you might have to intersect infinitely many sets.)

Comment: I haven't been able to prove this. I can't seem to define a $U$ such that $g(U) \cap U = 0$. Could you maybe add this to your answer?

Comment: @Geigercounter see here for example https://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205C-2011/freeactions.pdf

Comment: I don't immediately see how this relates to my question of properly discontinuous?

Comment: @Geigercounter read the proof of the Theorem on the second page.