# Different definitions of proper actions

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces

I want to compare three definitions for an action $G\times X\to X$ to be proper:

1. For each $x\in X$, there is a neighborhood $U\subseteq X$ such that $gU\cap U=\emptyset$ for all but finitely many $g\in G$.
2. For each $x,x'\in X$, there are neighborhoods $U,U'\subseteq X$ such that $gU\cap U'=\emptyset$ for all but finitely many $g\in G$.
3. For each compact subset $K\subseteq X$, we have $gK\cap K=\emptyset$ for all but finitely many $g\in G$.

The equivalence of (2) and (3) holds for locally compact $X$, see e.g. Lee's *Introduction into topological manifolds*. However, I don't see if the first definition is equivalent to the other ones and under which conditions ($X$ hausdorff?). Obviously, (2) implies (1). I think I could show the converse if I knew that
$$\{(x,gx);\,x\in X\text{ and }g\in G\}\subseteq X\times X$$
is closed if (1) holds. Is this clear?

Comment: (3) implies (1) is easy for locally compact $X$, is it not ?

Comment: Yes, I agree; but I fear that (1) is weaker than the other two statements …

Comment: Oops I'm stupid, sorry about that. I seem to recall that they were all equivalent in a locally compact setting... (but can't think of a proof)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be thinking of $G$ as a discrete group. For example, if $G$ is not discrete, then the last phrase in (3) would have to be replaced by "all $g$ outside of a compact subset of $G$."

Assuming $G$ is discrete and $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, (2) and (3) are both equivalent to the action being proper, as you noted. But (1) is definitely weaker. Consider the following example: Let $X=\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}$, and define an action of $\mathbb Z$ on $X$ by $n\cdot (x,y) = (2^n x, 2^{-n} y)$. This satisfies your condition (1), but it's not a proper action. The subset $K \times K \subseteq X\times X$ is compact, where $K = \{(x,y): \max(|x|,|y|)=1\}$,   but $\rho^{-1}(K\times K)$ contains the sequence $(n, (2^{-n},1))$, which has no convergent subsequence.

For more about these various definitions, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083696/1421) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2808280/1421).