# free and proper group action implies properly discontinuous

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold, and $G$ be a discrete group. The action $G\times X \rightarrow X$ is called free if for all $1\neq g\in G, x\in X, g\cdot x \neq x$. It is called proper if the map $G\times X \rightarrow X\times X, (g,x)\mapsto (g\cdot x, x)$ is proper.

Prove that this implies proper discontinuity. Huybrechts' Complex Geometry cites Bourbaki Topologie Generale and Dieck Transformation groups as a reference, but I can't find the statement in either of them.

Comment: You should write down what notion of proper discontinuity you are using here: There are many inequivalent notions floating around.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions?rq=1. Namely, see the references given in the accepted answer. More precisely, see Theorem 12.11 and the preceding discussion in J.Lee "Introduction to Topological Manifolds". Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly discontinuous action: equivalent definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming proper discontinuity means that for all $x \in X$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $gU \cap U \neq \emptyset$ implies $g = e.$

If $G$ were finite, we'd use the fact that $X$ is hausdorf and $gx \neq x$ for $g \neq e.$ In this case, there are open sets $U_g, V_g$ with $x \in U_g, gx \in V_g$ and $U_g \cap V_g = \emptyset.$ Then since $G$ acts continuously, $g^{-1} (V_g) \cap U_g$ is a neighborhood of $x.$ To get our final neighborhood, intersect these. Since $G$ finite, this is again a neighborhood.

But sadly $G$ is only discrete, with proper action. So we need to restrict somehow to only finitely many $g \in G.$ Here's the idea:

Let $U \ni x$ be contained in a compact set $C.$ Choose $U_g$ and $V_g$ as before, except we replace $U_g$ with $U \cap U_g.$ So $U_g \subset C$ for all $g.$ Since $G$ acts properly, we have that the preimage of $C \times C$ is compact in $G \times X.$ Since $G$ is discrete, the sets $(g, X)$ are open, and they form an open cover of any subset of $G \times X.$ By compactness, there are finitely many $g_i$ such that $(g_i, y)$ is mapped into $C \times C.$ Since this open cover is disjoint, these are the only $g_i$ that send any point in $C$ back into $C.$ In particular, this implies there are finitely many $g \in G$ such that $gU \cap U \neq \emptyset.$

Then I claim $W =\cap_i^n U_{g_i}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that's disjoint from $gW$ for all nontrivial $g.$ By definition, this is true for $g$ one of the $g_i.$ If $g$ is not one of the $g_i,$ then since $g(U) \cap U = \emptyset$ and $W \subset U$ we have $g(W) \cap W = \emptyset.$ Exactly as desired.

Comment: In fact, the definition of a properly discontinuous action used by the OP has one more requirement: If $x, y$ are not in the same $G$-orbit then $x, y$ admit neighborhoods with disjoint $G$-orbits.