# A question about Hausdorff quotient by Group Action. Also, there are some very related material in Lee's book.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a group acting on a topological space $X.$

I wanted to check the following statement.

> "Recall that the action is called even (or classically properly discontinuous) if for every point $x \in X$ (topological space) there exists an open set $U
> \in X$ such that $x \in U$ and $gU \cap U = \emptyset;$ unless $g = e:$ Under this condition, later, we shall see that the quotient map is a very special kind of map called a covering projection. Right now, you can directly verify that if $X$ is Hausdorff then $X/G$ is Hausdorff."

But, the problem is, I can't prove this. But, I can prove this with extra conditions like

$1)$ $G$ is finite or

$2)$ for any $x,y$ in different orbit there exists corresponding $W,V$ open and $gW \cap V = \emptyset$ for all (most ?) $g \in G.$

Is the statement wrong or I am not considering something?

Thank You.

Comment: Typically $X$ is assumed to be locally compact and "properly discontinuous" is defined for compact subsets, not just points (although with local compactness this may be equivalent?). Anyway see this: https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/M141/hausdorff.pdf . I don't think the statement is true otherwise.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions **and** https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/properly-discontinuous-action