# A quotient space of a manifold by a covering space action is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be a topological manifold and suppose there is a covering space action of a group $G$ on $M$. This means that each $x\in M$ has a neighbrohood $U$ such that $g_1(U)\cap g_2(U)$ nonempty implies $g_1=g_2$, for any $g_1,g_2\in G$. Then is it true that the quotient space $M/G$ is Hausdorff? (I am trying to show that $M/G$ is a manifold. The hypothesis that the action of $G$ is a covering space action gives that the projection $M\to M/G$ is a covering map, so $M/G$ is locally Euclidean. But I can't see why $M/G$ should be Hausdorff.)

Comment: This is false and examples were discussed on several occasions on MSE. The correct condition to require is *properness* of the action.

Comment: See the example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions/1083696#1083696).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see. Thanks!