# Group acting on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on some manifold $M$. For s subset $A\subseteq M$, let $G[A]:=\{g\in G\mid A\cap g.A\neq\emptyset\}$. We assume that $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $M$, that is:

- *Proper discontinuous:* For every $x\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ for which $G[U]$ is finite;
- *Free:* For very $g\in G$, if there is $x\in M$ for which $g.x=x$, then necessarily $g=\mathrm{id}_G$.

In order to prove that $M/G$ also has the structure of a manifold, we use the following:

**Lemma.**

1. If $K\subseteq M$ is compact, then $G[K]$ is finite.
2. Every $x\in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ for which $G[U]=\mathrm{id}_G$.

I am trying to prove this result.

For 1., I assume that there are distinct $g_k\in G[K]$ $(k\geq 0)$. Then we find $x_k\in K$ for which also $g_k.x_k\in K$. Since $G$ acts freely on $M$, also the $x_k$ are distinct. Both sequences $(x_k)_{k\geq 0}$ and $(g_k.x_k)_{k\geq 0}$ have a limit point because $K$ is compact.
Am I on the right track? How can I continue from here?

For 2., I feel like we should start with the open neighborbood $U$ of $x$ given by proper discontinuity, and in case $G[U]$ contains other elements than the identity, we remove them one by one until only the identity is left. However, I don't see how I can put this into practice...

Comment: Are your manifolds required to be Hausdorff?

Comment: @MoisheKohan They are Hausdorff and second-countable.

Comment: Then your conjecture is false: The quotient need not be Hausdorff, the properness condition you are using is too weak. See an example in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan OK, so 1. of the Lemma fails. Is there some mild assumption that we can add to $G$ to make it true?

Comment: You need a correct form of properness, you can find one on MSE (see the link) or Wikipedia.

Comment: Item 1 in your lemma is the correct definition of proper discontinuity.